# Can anyone suggest a simple way to update an SQLite database with changed data using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite which has no DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am converting a C# project from using an SQL Server Compact database to SQLite using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.
My main problem is that there is no equivalent of SqlCeDataAdapter (i.e. no SqliteDataAdapter) in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.
Can anyone suggest a simple way to update an SQLite database with changed data from a DataSet (the equivalent of DataAdapter.Update())?

I would prefer to use Microsoft.Data.Sqlite rather than System.Data.SQLite (which has an SqliteDataAdapter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write sql update queries for an SQLite database without the use of an adapter by using the SQLiteCommand method:

```
string cs = "Data Source=:memory:";
string stm = "SELECT * FROM table";

using var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
con.Open();

using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con);
string version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Source: https://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/

Comment: Thanks Ilias, 
I may have to do that, but I could have hundreds of changes to the data in the dataset.  DataAdapter.Update(MyChangeDataset) would apply all the changes in all the rows in one go. 
I am looking for an easier way if possible as this is used extensively in the project.

Comment: As there is no DataAdapter, running an SQL UPDATE command seems to be the only way.